# Check if specific level is set, and if so, log on that level

Tags: logging, log4net

I'm trying to write some extension methods for log4net and one requirement is that the user can specify which level he would like to have my extension log a message on.

Now I'd like to be able to check whether or not that level is even enabled in my log4net logger.

I know I can check

```cs
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(....);

if(log.IsDebugEnabled) 
{
   // log something
}
```

but is there a way, given a `log4net.Core.Level` variable, to check whether that level is enabled or not?

So I'm hoping there might be something like:

```cs
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(....);
log4net.Core.Level myLevel = Level.Warn;

if(log.IsLevelEnabled(myLevel))
{
   // log something
   log.Log(myLevel, message);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

**Solution:**  `peer` mentioned - hidden in one of the comments - how to do this:

> However you can get the logger implementation: `log.Logger.IsEnabledFor()...` And the `log.Logger.Log(...)` can help you, the `Log` function is not intended to be used directly.

So now I can easily use:

```cs
if(log.Logger.IsEnabledFor(myLevel)) 
{
   // log something 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make extention methods for ILog:

```cs
public static class Log4NetExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool IsLevelEnabled( this ILog log, log4net.Core.Level level)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static void LogAtLevel( this ILog log, log4net.Core.Level level, string message)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes - certainly I can - I was just hoping something like this might *already* be available in log4net ....

Comment: You only have the ILog interface https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.ILogMembers.html, which comes from you LogManager and that one is very simple. Nothing in there to help you at this point in time.

Comment: However you can get the logger implementation: log.Logger.IsEnabledFor()... And the log.Logger.Log(...) can help you, the Log function is not intended to use directly.

Comment: ***ah!*** that's exactly what I was looking for - `log.Logger.IsEnabledFor(level)` - thanks!!